# Cannot send message to just created channel

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to send a message to a channel just after I created it, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm using discord.js@v12

This is the code:

```js
message.guild.channels.create(cpl, 'text').then(ma => {
  ma.setParent(cat);
  ma.lockPermissions();
}).catch(err => console.log(err))

let nChannel = bot.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === cpl)
console.log(nChannel)
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("New Ticket")

nChannel.send(embed)
```

This is what is logged to the console:

```
Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
```

Comment: What was the output of `console.log(nChannel)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because you're not waiting for the channel to be created before trying to send the message. In the same way you wait for it to be ready before using `.setParent()` and `.lockPermissions()`, you should wait before using `.send()`.
Here's how I would do it:

```js
message.guild.channels.create(cpl, 'text').then(async (newChannel) => {
  // You're inside .then, so all of this is happening AFTER the channel is created

  // Wait for .setParent and .lockPermissions to fulfill
  await newChannel.setParent(cat)
  await newChannel.lockPermissions()

  // You can now send your message
  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("New Ticket")
  newChannel.send(embed)
})
```

Comment: Okay, but this is a new error:
Error [GUILD_CHANNEL_ORPHAN]: Could not find a parent to this guild channel.

Comment: I removed lockPermissions() and it works! Anyway thank you very much, have a nice day)

Comment: Happy to hear that :)